# How to check Null values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel framework to develop  web application ,i am using soft-deletes so while fetching the data from database i have to check weather the column is null or not ,for that i wrote a following query

**QueryBuilder**

```
$today= "2022-09-23 00:00:00";
$this->repository->pushCriteria(new WhereCriteria('date_of_leaving', $today));
```

**querylog**

```
array (
    'query' => 'select * from `employees` where `date_of_leaving` = ? and `employees`.`deleted_at` is null',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '2022-09-23 00:00:00',
    ),
    'time' => 2.36,
  ),
```

**table structure**

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email           | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| joining_date    | timestamp       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| manager_id      | bigint unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| image_path      | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_of_leaving | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| still_working   | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at      | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**data**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| date_of_leaving     | deleted_at          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2022-09-23 00:00:00 | 2022-09-23 11:47:11 |
| 2022-09-23 00:00:00 | 2022-09-23 12:36:46 |
| 2022-09-23 00:00:00 | 2022-09-23 13:09:55 |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| 2022-09-06 00:00:00 | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | 2022-09-23 11:45:01 |
| NULL                | NULL                |
| NULL                | NULL                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Actually in database three matching records are there with the above condition but this query is not fetching the data ,i was suspecting **deteled_at** was considering  **NULL** as **string**

Comment: deleted_at is a part of laravel's "soft delete" feature. It should not be the issue. Can you show the data in your table? And would be good if you can post your "query builder" code (PHP)

Comment: Check if your model has the SoftDeletes trait, then laravel will handle the rest. I am not sure if you are using eloquent,  but you can use the withTrashed method if you still want to retrieve the deleted records.

Comment: @Prometheus,i am using softDeletes trait

Comment: @RakeshMehta,i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

array (
'query' => 'select * from `employees` where `date_of_leaving` Is Null and `employees`.`deleted_at` is null',
'bindings' =>
array (
0 => '2022-09-23 00:00:00',
),
'time' => 2.36,
),

Comment: I am using [this package](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) ,so i am not able to control the query format

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, i believe the package you are using does not support Laravel's softDelete() feature.

```
$this->repository->pushCriteria(new WhereCriteria(['date_of_leaving',=> $today,'deleted_at'=>Null]));
```